# Subdomain rewrite not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, subdomain

I'm attempting to do a subdomain rewrite for apache using a .htaccess file.

Currently:
domain.com/subdomain

Desired result:
subdomain.domain.com

This is what I have so far...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^subdomain/(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Any help would be great appreciated!

Cheers,
Wayne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\. [NC]
RewriteRule . - [S=2]

RewriteRule ^subdomain/(.+)$ http://subdomain.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^subdomain/?$ http://subdomain.domain.com [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That never did the trick unfortunately. I have the subdomain setup to redirect over to domain.com/directory (directory = location where subdomain is pointing). This was created within cPanel.

Could there be a conflict there somehow?

Comment: I found out what the issue was. Apparently I set it up as a redirect and should have left it alone. So it was jumping over to the sub-directory, and not its own sub-domain. Embarrassing I know, thank you for the help Justin!